# SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, rsa

I'm trying to SSH into a Debian from Ubuntu. I already have a RSA key; it's the same key that I use got my Git.

I copied the key from Ubuntu to Debian using:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@ip-address
```

Then I modified `sshd_config` on Debian to include the following:

> RSAAuthentication yes
>
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
>
> PasswordAuthentication no

And I restarted my SSH service. Now I try to SSH into from Ubuntu using

```
ssh -v root@ip-addr
```

but I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.64 [10.0.1.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/koushatalebian/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/koushatalebian/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e2:af:83:f8:df:e2:15:db:77:30:e1:6b:e7:dc:77:99
debug1: Host '10.0.1.64' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/koushatalebian/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/koushatalebian/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm basically want to force SSH to only occur through publickey authentication.

I've read every other post related to this topic, and none of them worked for me. That is why I've created this as a separate post.

**EDIT**

Changing `StrictModes` from `yes` to `no` in `sshd_config` fixed the problem. Is this safe to do?

**EDIT 2**
This is the log for the SSH on the server:

```
May  5 18:23:55 lemaker sshd[2591]: Connection from 10.0.1.37 port 42748
May  5 18:23:55 lemaker sshd[2591]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.0.1.37"
May  5 18:23:55 lemaker sshd[2591]: Failed publickey for root from 10.0.1.37 port 42748 ssh2
May  5 18:23:55 lemaker sshd[2591]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.37 [preauth]
```

Comment: You're trying to authenticate with your **public key**. You need to use your **private key** - usually the one without an extension.

Comment: What is this setting? "PermitRootLogin yes"

Comment: Disabling `StrictModes` is probably a bad idea, as it means you have a key file that ssh thinks is not protected enough by permissions to be trusted.  You can choose to trust it anyway, but you do so at your peril.  It's probably better to find the file(s) it doesn't like and fix the permissions on them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not want to offer your .pub as your credentials.  You want to use your private key on your end, so you should probably be doing

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@ip-addr
```

which is the deault key to use, so you can just leave off the `-i` flag altogether

Also, make sure you have `PermitRootLogin yes` if you're going to login as root through ssh

Comment: Done and done, but still exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hold on, so I changed `StrictModes` to `no` and now it works. Is that okay?

Comment: You should probably double check what the permissions are on your keys, you want 600 on your private key and 644 on the public key.  And on the server you'll want 644 on authorized_keys and that the `.ssh` directory on each is 700

Comment: I did, but if I go back to `yes` for `StrictModes` I get the same problem.

Comment: Did you try looking in `/var/log/secure` (for Fedora/RHEL type systems) or I think it's `/var/log/auth.log` for Ubuntu to see what the server doesn't like?

Comment: On the computer I want to log into, it says `Connection closed by 10.0.1.37 [preauth]`

Comment: Try adding `LogLevel DEBUG` to your `sshd_config` then try to login again, you should see a line like ` Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/<user>/.ssh` or something like that for the actual file that it's unhappy about

Comment: I didn't get that response. I'll post what I got in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77031/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-kousha).

Comment: can anyone please provide some assistance? I have been searching the internet for solutions for past 6 hours and I haven't found any that work. I am trying to ssh into a mac osx (high sierra) from raspberry pi 4. i set up remote login on mac but every time i try the command stated above, i get permission denied. I tried the other way around and it works fine (ssh into raspberry pi). I removed the .ssh folders and started fresh, but still the same issue. I tried all the suggestions in this thread but nothing, even the `StrictModes` to no. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SpencerTrinh that would probably be best asked as a new question at either the Unix and Linux site or at superuser

Comment: @EricRenouf Changing the permissions on the keys was all I needed to do to fix the problem for me

Comment: Be mindful of the file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config NOT /etc/ssh/ssh_config!! The answer is helpful but this problem still cost me so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I would make up a new key pair and use it instead.  This just tests stuff out locally, but simply tar up the .ssh directory and put it on the remote server to make two-way ssh possible, if you only want one-way, then don't have the public key in both authorized_keys files:

```
$ pwd
/home/testuser
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa):[ENTER]
Created directory '/home/testuser/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):[ENTER]
Enter same passphrase again:[ENTER]
Your identification has been saved in /home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
[...]
$ cd .ssh
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw------- 1 testuser testuser 1679 May 5 13:49 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser 401 May 5 13:49 id_rsa.pub
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
$ ssh 127.0.0.1
The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 0f:dd:ed:e3:bf:a1:c8:3f:fd:b2:0d:e8:1f:ee:29:f8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-36-generic x86_64)
[...]
Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

$ exit
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Comment: "simply tar up the .ssh directory and put it on the remote server" is a terrible solution. Private keys should, in general, never leave the machines they were generated on. It's the public half of the key that needs to get propagated around (.../.ssh/*.pub).

Comment: Right, that is why the very first thing I said was "I would make up a new key pair and use it instead. " But thanks.